# Views - Multiple filters on a single field with multiple values allowed

Tags: views

I have a field in my view with unlimited number of values. I need to have the ability to filter on combinations of these categories (i.e. DOCTOR & SANTA MONICA & TAKES INSURANCE. I want to have 3 filters, all on the same field, but when I do this, the resulting view set is empty.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to do this? I'm baffled!

Thanks!

Jeff

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  It would be helpful if you provided more information about the view you have  defined.  Tell us if it is page or a block, whether its format is content or fields, which fields, what exact you have set your filters as (taxonomy fields?), and whether you have defined any relationships or contextual filters.  This information will help us figure out what is working or not.  I also recommend that you watch the video series at http://dev.nodeone.se/node/701, taming the Beast for more about how to use views.

Comment: The view is a page of data type PEOPLE.  The data type has a field called CATEGORY which is a node reference to another data type also called CATEGORY.  There are 100 records in CATEGORY, so each person in PEOPLE can be classified with as many of these categories as the user desires.  So as I stated above, a person could be a DOCTOR, TAKES INSURANCE, SANA MONNICA or LAWYER, HAS CHILDREN, LIKES ANIMALS.  On the view, I would like to have 3 drop downs, allowing the user to choose one of these categories in each.  The list is long and users find it difficult to use Drupal's multi-select box.

Comment: As an experiment, I changed on of these drop downs to allow multi-selections and see that this does not provide a solution.  The resulting set ORs the results, that is, if I choose DOCTOR and LOVES WINE, I get a list of DOCTORS and a list of LOVES WINE, not a list of DOCTORS AND LOVES WINE.  Thanks in advance!